# How to access request/session data when in form parse error block?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm in onError block which returns view, this view has implicit Flash and ApplicationContext passed into. ApplicationContext keeps user data from session, and I don't know how to access it from onError:

```
  def userFormSubmitted() = Action(parse.form(dataForm, onErrors = (formWithErrors: Form[UserForm]) => {
    // to get rid of error I provide these 2 implicits
    // implicit val applicationContext: ApplicationContext = ApplicationContext(None)
    // implicit val flash: Flash = Flash()
    BadRequest(views.html.user.userFormPage(formWithErrors))
  })) { implicit request =>
    val data = request.body
    // rest of code
  }
```

ApplicationContext is created by a trait:

```
case class ApplicationContext(user: Option[User])

trait ApplicationController extends Controller {

  implicit def context[A](implicit request: Request[A]): ApplicationContext = {
   //skipped
  }

}
```

Template has it injected as:

```
@(dataForm: Form[UserForm])(implicit messages: Messages, context: ApplicationContext, flash: Flash)
@main("User Edit Form") { ... }
```

If there is bad data onError is entered, but without commented implicits code doesn't even compile with the error: 
could not find implicit value for parameter context: traits.ApplicationContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've reached the upper limit of what you can do in the `parse.form` body parser.

If you switch to using the [`bindFromRequest` approach to handling form submission](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Validating-a-form-in-an-Action) you can get those implicits into scope and everything will work:

```
def userFormSubmittedNew() = Action { implicit request =>

  dataForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest(views.html.user.userFormPage(formWithErrors))
    },
    goodForm => {
      ...
    }
  )
}
```